# How can i remove blank columns from an excel file through java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a testdata.xlsx which contains data in form of key-value pair. The java code that I have implemented enters a key and the corresponding value below it . In some cases the key-value will be blank , hence creating a blank column . Please suggest how can i remove the blank columns so that the existing data will be available serially without any blank columns between them .

I couldn't find any solution .

NA

NA

Comment: "java code that I have implemented" - share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that file will contain only 2 row (1-Key, 2-Value), then check first 2 cell in each column. If both are null then remove that column using Apache POI API.

If not, you have to check entire column cell for any character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sheet.shiftColumns(colno + 1, endcolno, -1);`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#shiftColumns-int-int-int-).
Or just `sheet.setColumnHidden(colno);` to hide the column, which is easier when
formulas are involved.

Finding blank columns you probably already did.